# npm install - git problems

Tags: git, npm, zsh, steroids

I am having problems getting the following command to work. I posted to the steroids.js forums, but this seems to be more of a generic git problem. All the repo's with a leading "git@" on the url fail.

#### command

```
npm install steroids -g
```

#### errors

```
npm ERR! git clone https://git@github.com/AppGyver/incubator-ripple.git Cloning into bare repository '/Users/kbaker/.npm/_git-remotes/https-git-github-com-AppGyver-incubator-ripple-git-2c417fa2'...
npm ERR! git clone https://git@github.com/AppGyver/incubator-ripple.git 

npm ERR! git clone https://git@github.com/AppGyver/ios-sim.git 
npm ERR! git clone https://git@github.com/AppGyver/ios-sim.git fatal: Unable to look up git@github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: Unable to look up git@github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

I downloaded the github repo of the below npm package, adjusted the packages.json file to use repo url's that do not fail and I am still getting errors about missing packages.

I've tried updating npm and git commands. Could this have somethign to do with the fact that I'm running zsh?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Your clone url is incorrect. You're using:

```
https://git@github.com/AppGyver/incubator-ripple.git
```

Either use ssh:

```
git@github.com:AppGyver/incubator-ripple.git
```

or https:

```
https://github.com/AppGyver/incubator-ripple.git
```

but not both

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this issue because of my proxy settings.

You can try installing it with:

`npm install git+https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids -g`

but I suggest configuring **git** to transform ***git*** urls to ***https*** with:

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

and then retry:

`npm install steroids -g`